# Blockchain info wallet check payment

Tags: python, api, request, blockchain, blockchain.info-api

I am trying to create bill for payment and send to my customer via telegram bot:
I am using blockchain API V2-https://blockchain.info/api/api receive .my code is:

```
xpub='***'
keyk='02e57f1***'
url='https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub='+str(xpub)+'&callback=https%3A%2F%2Fdoors03.ru&key='+keyk
x=requests.get(url)
r=x.json()
r=r['address']
```

r -is an address which was made.
I am sending it to my costumer(by the way is there any way to send address with exact sum for pay ) . After I want to check is payment was received:

```
data={ "Content-Type": "text/plain","key":keyk,"addr":r,"callback":"https%3A%2F%2Fdoors03.ru","onNotification":"KEEP", "op":"RECEIVE"}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

and this is the response - u'{\n  "message" : "Internal handlers error"\n}'

What I am doing wrong? How to check payments? How to send address with exact sum of btc or ethereum?

Comment: have you had a look at the blockchain package in pypi? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blockchain/1.4.0

Answer (score 1):

> Sorry, i don't have enough reputation to post a comment, so this is
> the only option i have. @egorkh have you solved this problem? Maybe
> you have received explanation from blockchain.info support? I have
> sent them a question about that, but they are answering for too long.

**UPDATE:** Finally, i have found solution.

In my case, reason of "*Internal handlers error*" message is in a wrong interpretation of their API.

As they haven't implemented *balance_update* request in their java-api, i did it on my own and i did it in wrong way.

I have put this parameters:

> {"key":keyk,"addr":r,"callback":"https%3A%2F%2Fdoors03.ru","onNotification":"KEEP", "op":"RECEIVE"}

as post parameters, like in other methods they have provided in api. In those methods parameters are URLEncoded like you did with callback link. But...

*In this HTML request they must be sent as plain text in json format without any special encoding, like that:*

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("addr", address);
    params.put("callback", callbackUrl);
    params.put("key", apiCode);
    params.put("onNotification", keepOnNotification? "KEEP" : "DELETE");
    params.put("confs", Integer.toString(confirmationCount));
    params.put("op", StringUtils.isBlank(operationType) ? "ALL" : operationType);
    
//parse parameters map to json string(that's optional: you can write it  directly as string)
String body = new Gson().toJson(params);

if (requestMethod.equals("POST")) {
    byte[] postBytes = body.getBytes("UTF-8");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postBytes.length));
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postBytes);
    conn.getOutputStream().close();
}
```

The main reason of your error may be that you put "Content-Type": "text/plain" in data object *(, and maybe encoded callback url)* .

Comment: hi , you can check  balance this way https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/1D***            1D*** - is  adress wich you want to check.                                                
 now i am looking for solution for etherium address . this one not work

Comment: i remove content type and paste link without any encode . still the same error (

Comment: @egorkh well, after month of using their api  i have found that their servers certainly have problems and support is not the best at helping. I can suggest you to test raw request using [restlet-client extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restlet-client-rest-api-t/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm). Just import my [test case](https://pastebin.com/C1hGwNmv) as "Restlet client Repository" and set proper api key and callback. You should receive proper response.